# Visual Studio 2013 C Syntax outlining

Tags: c, syntax, visual-studio-2013, outline

Is there a way in Visual Studio 2013 to outline (in red) undeclared C functions?
It seems that by default VS2013 considers that each unknown function is implicit.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Visual Studio is notoriously bad at the modern C standards, and is pretty much stuck at C89. The 2013 version [improved on this a bit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh409293.aspx), but nothing much.

I believe it indeed still takes undeclared functions to implicitly return `int`. The IDE just follows the compiler in this regard (which it should...).

What you probably already know is that you can compile some but not all C code as C++, and then most C99 rules like the one you're on about here come into play. Just save your source file as `.cpp` or equivalent and presto.

That, or use a decent IDE that has support for the language you use.